# if any email is set in textview then open the default email client if clicked

Tags: android

In my app if any number is set then on clicking it starts a call on that number, and if any website link is given then also it shows that underline and on clicking that it opens the browser.

Similarly, I want to open the email client if any email address is set in the textview and show it underline.

Comment: what mean you want to open ? the mail id is direct open to send mail is it ?

Comment: yes, it will open send mail

Comment: so you just want to set mail id in **To:abc.xyz.com**  mail screen and user can edit body area > send is it ?

Comment: yes,actually i thought if there was something android provided then it would be quite easy.

Comment: i post my answer if its good for you then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns.html) you will get about patterns.

Initially when the screen starts you need to check for the type of value and then set the styles and click functions for your `TextView` like below. I guess you know about how to send emails, make calls and open a web browser with a link. I have made three click listeners but using one is good. You can have a flags for that and depending on that you can make operations instead.

```
public void setStyleAndFunction(CharSequence target) {
    if(Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches()) {
       textview.setonClickListener() {
         //   send email
       }
    }
    if(Patterns.PHONE.matcher(target).matches()) {
       textview.setonClickListener() {
            // make call
       }
    }
    if(Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(target).matches()) {
       //set style (underline)
       textview.setonClickListener() {
           //open a web browser
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try It works for me :

Just write this code **TextView ClickEvent** or set as **Linkify** and call this.

```
    Intent i2 = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i2.setType("text/html");
    i2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC,new String[]{"Your CC Mail ID"});  
    i2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"Your TO Mail ID"});
    i2.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your Mail Body");
```